# Passing one to many core data between view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am having problems passing data between view controllers.

All three view controllers are table views.

```
 WorkoutTypeVC
 WorkoutSetVC
 WorkoutExerciseVC
```

I have three entities,

```
WorkoutType
    workouts(->WorkoutSet) One to Many
WorkoutSet
    exercises(->WorkoutExercise) One to Many
    workoutType(->WorkoutType) Inverse
WorkoutExercise
    workoutSet(->WorkoutSet) Inverse
```

I am able to switch between all three view controllers, WorkoutTypeVC loads correctly showing all entries, When selected WorkoutSetVC is loaded showing the correct entries corresponding to the selection made from WorkoutTypeVC.

But when i select an entry from WorkoutSetVC, WorkoutExerciseVC loads but is empty, Even the title of the selection doesn't load.

I have used the same code which i used when switching from WorkoutTypeVC and WorkoutSetVC.

Below is the code for switching views in WorkoutType.m file:

```
-(void)fetchWorkoutTypes
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =
    [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"WorkoutType"];
    NSString *cacheName = [@"WorkoutType" stringByAppendingString:@"Cache"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"workoutType" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                 initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                 sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:cacheName];
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Fetch failed: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self fetchWorkoutTypes];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    WorkoutType *workoutType = (WorkoutType *)[self.fetchedResultsController
                                        objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = workoutType.workoutType;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d)", workoutType.workouts.count];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WorkoutType *workoutType = (WorkoutType *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    WorkoutSetViewController *detailViewController = [[WorkoutSetViewController alloc] initWithWorkoutType:workoutType];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Below is the code for WorkoutSetVC.m

```
-(void)fetchWorkoutSets
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =
    [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"WorkoutSet"];
    NSString *cacheName = [@"WorkoutSet" stringByAppendingString:@"Cache"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"workoutName" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                 initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                 sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:cacheName];
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Fetch failed: %@", error);
    }
}
- (id)initWithWorkoutType:(WorkoutType *)workoutType
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self)
    {
        self.workoutType = workoutType;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = self.workoutType.workoutType;

    [self fetchWorkoutSets];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.workoutType.workouts.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    WorkoutSet *workoutSet = [self.workoutType.workouts.allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = workoutSet.workoutName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d)", workoutSet.exercises.count];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WorkoutSet *workoutSet = (WorkoutSet *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    WorkoutExerciseTableViewController *detailViewController = [[WorkoutExerciseTableViewController alloc] initWithWorkoutSet:workoutSet];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Below is the code for WorkoutExercise.m

```
- (id)initWithWorkoutSet:(WorkoutSet *)workoutSet
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self)
    {
        self.workoutSet = workoutSet;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)fetchWorkoutExercises
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =
   [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"WorkoutExercise"];
   NSString *cacheName = [@"WorkoutExercise" stringByAppendingString:@"Cache"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"exerciseName" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                 initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                 sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:cacheName];
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Fetch failed: %@", error);
    } 
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = self.workoutSet.workoutName;
    [self fetchWorkoutExercises];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    WorkoutExercise *exercise = [self.workoutSet.exercises.allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = exercise.exerciseName;

    return cell;
}
```

Not sure as to what i need to do for the third view controller to list all the entries, Even the title for the third view controller doesn't load which is coded in the ViewDidLoad Method.

Thank You

Comment: In your WorkoutSetViewController, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` accesses the  objects directly via `self.workoutType.workouts.allObjects`, but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` uses a fetched results controller (FRC). This does not make sense. If the table view is driven by a FRC, *all* data source methods must use the FRC.

Comment: And btw. generating an array from `self.workoutType.workouts` with `allObjects` is also problematic, because the order of the array elements can be random. - In other words: Use a fetched results controller properly!

Comment: Thanks mate, thats the section i had somehow overlooked when coding for the third view controller. Works properly now

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad that it helped! - I have added it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (I assume) the inconsistent use of data sources in the second (and third?)
view controller.

In your `WorkoutSetViewController`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` accesses the objects directly via `self.workoutType.workouts.allObjects`, but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` uses a fetched results controller (FRC). This does not make sense. If the table view is driven by a FRC, all data source methods must use the FRC.

Perhaps `self.fetchedResultsController` is `nil` in the second view controller?
Then the `workoutSet` passed to the third view controller would be `nil`, which would
explain that no title is set and no objects are displayed.

And generating an array from `self.workoutType.workouts` with `allObjects` is also problematic, because the order of the array elements can be random.

The second view controller should use a fetched results controller to display 
all `WorkoutSet` objects related to the given `workoutType`.

And the third view controller should use a fetched results controller to display 
all `WorkoutExercise` objects related to the given `workoutSet`.

**UPDATE:** `fetchWorkoutSets` in WorkoutSetVC.m should look like this:

```
-(void)fetchWorkoutSets
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"WorkoutSet"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"workoutType = %@", self.workoutType];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"workoutName" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                 initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                 sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Fetch failed: %@", error);
    }
}
```

The *predicate* is important to fetch only workout sets that are related to `self.workoutType`.

And similarly, `fetchWorkoutExercises` in WorkoutExercise.m would use the predicate

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"workoutSet = %@", self.workoutSet];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

to fetch only exercises that are related to `self.workoutSet`.

For the data source methods, have a look at the [NSFetchedResultsController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it contains sample code that you can copy
and adapt to your needs. Or you create a fresh Xcode iOS application with the "Master-Detail Application" template and select the "Core Data" checkbox. That will also give you
sample code.

For example, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in WorkoutSetVC.m you would replace

```
WorkoutSet *workoutSet = [self.workoutType.workouts.allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

by

```
WorkoutSet *workoutSet = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Ive tried implementing the FRC, but still doesn't seem to work correctly. for example: Workout Type 1 and Workout Type 2 in WorkoutType Entity. Core 1 in Workout Type 1 and Core 2 in Workout Type 3.  When i reach the third view controller, it displays the Data in Core 1 for both scenarios. I will edit code used above.

Comment: I take it I am still not using FRC right...How would i go about changing     self.workoutType.workouts with allObjects so that it uses FRC...

Comment: Thanks most of it seems to be working now, but get this slight error if i select the second entry within WorkoutType: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CoreData: FATAL ERROR: The persistent cache of section information does not match the current configuration.  You have illegally mutated the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descriptor without either disabling caching or using +deleteCacheWithName:

Comment: @user2512523: Use `cacheName:nil` when creating the FRC (I have updated the answer accordingly). A cache is only useful if you also use a `sectionNameKeyPath`, which you don't. And even then, I would not use it unless you have a performance problem. The error occurs because you have to delete the cache explicitly if you change the fetch request (e.g. the predicate).

Comment: Thank you very much! ios newbie here, and you've probably saved me hours on this :)

Comment: Hi, wandering if you could have a look at this question and see if you can possible help. Thank You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342511/sort-descriptor-not-functioning-correctly-or-consistently